# A question on plural: The A(s) of B and C is (are)...?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

I often come up with this type of sentences:

- The A(s) of B and C is (are)...?

For example:

- The *size* of the *batteries* of node 1 and node 2 *is* (*are*) 100 mAh and 200 mAh, respectively.

In this case, each *node* has *only one battery*.

I am not sure about whether:

1. I should use '**size**' or '**sizes**'?
2. I should use '**battery**' or '**batteries**'?
3. I should use '**is**' or '**are**'?

Thank you very much!

Comment: *The size of the batteries of node 1 **and** node 2 are 100mAh and 200mAh, respectively.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one instance of something you place a singular and if you have more than one you place a plural. So what does this mean:

1. If you have more than one size of a battery you say **"sizes"** though it's absolutely strange to have more than one size of a battery. Mostly a **size** of a battery refers to the **dimensions**. You can have an *AA-sized battery* or an *AAA-sized battery* for instance. If you wish to speak about the amount of charge they can hold then you should use the word "**capacity**" instead.
2. If you have only one battery for both nodes you say **"battery"** else you say **"batteries"** - each for every node.
3. You have one battery then you say **"is"** else you say **"are"** because there's more than one.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all of you for your response.

I searched the problem on the internet and find the following example. Suppose A and B are two person.

1. the house of A and B  (x) This is may be wrong because the two houses may not be the same one;
2. the houses of A and B (x) This may be wrong because the houses may not bethe common property of A and B;
3. the house of both A and B (x) This is may be wrong because the two houses may not be the same one;
4. the houses of both A and B (x)  This may be wrong because the houses may not bethe common property of A and B;

It would be better to say:

```
'the house of A and that of B is/are ...'
```

Comment: You shouldn't answer your own question with another question but here's my comment. The first implies a house that belongs to both A and B. Second is ambiguate, since it can mean several houses belonging to A and several houses belonging to B or houses that belong to A and B together. 3rd implies the same meaning as the first one. The 4th implies several houses that belong to both A and B.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I meant to added one comment to the question but I found comments do not have proper paragraph styles, so I answered my own question. Do you mean that the first of the following sentences is wrong? 1) The house of A and B is made of wood and made of metal, respectively. 2) The houses of A and B are made of wood and made of metal, respectively.

Comment: **The house of A and B is made of wood and made of metal, respectively** - means that one house that is the property of A and B together is made of both wood and metal but separately.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not that easy to understand.

Answer (score -1):

'Sizes' sounds better, because you're speaking about differently sized batteries. If all the nodes used the same battery model, it would be different. However, better than sizes, I'd use "capacities", since size is normally used to refer to the physical length, width and thickness of the battery.

Comment: If the OP uses "**sizes**" or "**capacities**" then he speaks about two instances of a size of a battery.